# Android: Respond to volume down from wired headset

Tags: android, keycode, headset, android-hardware

How do I intercept volume down button event from a wired headset?

The story is: There is that headset with a 3.5mm TRRS plug and a single button. Unfortunately, that button applies 470Ω which means "Volume down" instead of a simple short (0Ω) to signal "Play/Pause" as required from [Google specs](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec).

I would have somehow intercepted it but - It's not a good idea to intercept just any "Volume down" call.

Is there a way to even distinguish keypress by wired headphone from key-presses from the device buttons?

Thanks